# How to involve the Back Button when using .load() ajax request?

Tags: jquery

This is why I don't like Ajax, because of the back button being worthless.  How do you make it not so worthless when working with a .load() request for example?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Ugh, please don't do this. I hate twitter for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a plugin, for example, to jQuery:
http://tkyk.github.com/jquery-history-plugin/